# spoon.sh doesn't open up for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, pentaho, spoon

In Pentaho, `spoon.sh` doesn't execute properly and gives these errors.

I am trying to execute `spoon.sh` from putty and I have a Ubuntu Linux server running on cloud?

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
        at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:582)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
```

How to overcome these errors?

Comment: how do you expect to open a GTK based java GUI over a ssh connection?

Comment: I want gui to edit jobs and transformations,everytime editing on windows and moving to linux is the solution?

Comment: how and where you edit the jobs is another question, but you definitly can't edit the jobs on a headless server with the spoon GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spoon is a GUI interface and you can-not open spoon in non-GUI(like putty).

if you want to run the transformation or job you created in ubuntu linux server then execute using kitchen.sh or pan.sh.

Comment: job execution is done and its running successfully too..client asking the above requirement because jobs and transformation cannot be edited on linux server. so coming back to windows editing jobs/trans and putting back to linux they want us to avoid and come up with a solution..

Comment: above thing is not possible?
what kind of changes you want? if you want to change database connection and all then you can do those things by using parameterized approach in which you need not have to change anything in ktr or kjb file you simply have to do changes in your text files.

Comment: yeah only for changing connections and paths ,occassionaly..what is this parameterized approach?

Comment: instead of directly specifying hostname,database name you can pass parameters in that column and store your hostname,database name in one text file, so when ever you want to change any of them you can directly change it into that text file in this way your transformation doesn't affect. 
press clt+space in hostname or database filed and you will get some idea. or google it about different types of database connection something like that..

Comment: looks like a solution..any helpful links can you post here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with tunneling your X11. To solve it, you should install and run Xserver (Xming, for example) on your Windows machine, then enable X11 forwarding in SSH client (Putty or whatever).

[image]

[image]